# How to make entire div change color on hover using css?

Tags: css

I have the following:

```
    <div id="side-menu" class="sidebar-nav span2">
        <div class="sidebar-link"><span>Link 1</span></div>
        <div class="sidebar-link"><span>Link 2</span></div>
    </div>
```

I'm trying to make each of the two divs change color when you hover over them - whether you hover over the text of off to the right or left of the text.  Currently the color changes only if I hover over the text.  Any idea how this can be done?  Here's my fiddle with css:

http://jsfiddle.net/PTSkR/56/

Comment: You should probably remove those `<span>` tags, they look pretty redundant (in this example at least)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You have a space in the hover selector.  This matters because the space is the descendant selector in CSS

```
div.sidebar-link :hover{
    background-color: #E3E3E3;
}
```

This means that only hovered descendants of `.sidebar-link` are affected by the rules.  Remove the space.

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/PTSkR/57/

Comment: In Firefox, the space between the class and the hover selector causes the css to fail. Removing the space makes it work again. Like so:
div.sidebar-link:hover{

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this easily by this following code: [Link](https://jsfiddle.net/primalshade/6zur5b4m/)

```css
.cstDiv{
    padding:10px;
    width:55px;
}

div.cstDiv:hover{
    background-color:gray;    
    color:white;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
   <div>
       <div class="cstDiv">Link I</div>
       <div class="cstDiv">Link II</div>
       <div class="cstDiv">Link III</div>
       <div class="cstDiv">Link IV</div>
   </div>
```