# On hover li change li link color

Tags: html, css

I am struggling to change the font color of that particular li when hover over .
 The text is hyperlinked. Currently the font color is changing when you hover over the link.But I want it to be happened on hover over whole li.

Here is my code

```
<nav class="top_menu">
    <ul class="black_high">
        <li class="first"> <a href="#">Home</a>

        </li>
        <li> <a href="#">news</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/squidraj/h2zu5xx2/

I am not sure if I have to use some kind of js/jquery to achieve this? Please suggest. Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make entire div change color on hover using css?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16630558/how-to-make-entire-div-change-color-on-hover-using-css)

Comment: Thanks for the dup url. My search skill is zero it seems.Deserved to be down voted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need any script or plugin, just the right CSS. In your CSS, change the line:

```
.top_menu ul li a:hover
```

To:

```
.top_menu ul li:hover a
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/h2zu5xx2/1/